# COUNTIF function with dates in next 90 days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm really struggling with this and hope someone can help!

I have an excel sheet and I need to write COUNTIF or COUNTIFS function that will count all the cells in a range (let's say it's a row so F2:N2) that have a date falling within the next 90 days. I have a cell on the sheet that gives today's date (R2) #excel but not sure I even need that! Many Thanks

I currently have =COUNTIF($F$2:$N$2,"<="&TODAY()+90) but it doesn't appear to be working

Comment: Hi @Yair, can you clarify a little bit for me? The range is F2:N2 and the value or criteria I want to meet is any date within the next 90 days

Answer (score 1):

If by "not working" you mean you are getting the wrong result, that is because your formula is only testing if the Date is earlier than 90 days in the future. So it will include all dates prior to `TODAY()`.

To exclude the dates prior to `TODAY()`, you can try:

```
=COUNTIFS($F$2:$N$2,"<="&TODAY()+90,F2:N2,">="&TODAY())
```

If by "not working" you mean something else, please elaborate.